# How to build logic to auto notify users using FCM?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are working on an app in which a user can click for 15 seconds and the highest number of clicks go on the leader boards. Firebase is being used for storing data and we just started integrating FCM into the app.
Storing users in following format on Firebase:

```
"users":{
"userAuid" : {
    "bestscore" : "30",
    "dispname" : "usrea",
    "image" : "https://",
    "sortscore" : -30,
    "uid" : "userAuid"
  },
  "userBuid" : {
    "bestscore" : "200",
    "dispname" : "KilleRz Moves Ayub",
    "image" : "https://xxxxx",
    "sortscore" : -200,
    "uid" : "userBuid"
  },
"userCuid" : {
    "bestscore" : "276",
    "dispname" : "KilleRz Moves Ayub",
    "image" : "https://xxxxx",
    "sortscore" : -276,
    "uid" : "userCuid"
  }....so on
}
```

Now, a logic has to be built in which suppose userA makes a higher score than B and C then both B and C would get notified that their score has been beaten, or if B makes more score than C, then C gets notified and so on.

Please, can someone tell how can this be done using Firebase for Android. We are storing FCM tokens separately in a node. Thanks.